# Scrapy Spider: crawl a list of urls, starting from line n

Tags: python, scrapy

I am crawling a list of URLs from a text file using Scrapy Spider. I am rather new to Python and Scrapy, I am just having to wing it to get this task done.

My list of URLs is rather large, so this is how I have implemented it:

```py
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http.request import Request
import time

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "example"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]


    def __init__(self, filename=None, delay=5, start_line = 0):
        self.currentline = 0
        self.download_delay = int(delay)
        self.filename = filename
        self.start_line = int(start_line)



    def start_requests(self):
        with open(self.filename, 'r') as f:
            for url in f.readlines():
                self.currentline +=1

                if self.currentline < self.start_line:
                    continue
                else:
                    print(self.currentline)
                    yield Request(url.strip(), self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        logfilename = 'log'
        with open(logfilename, 'a') as f:
            f.write('Crawled line ' + str(self.currentline) + ' of ' + self.filename + ': ' + response.url + '\n')
```

I am not parsing anything right now, I'll worry about that later, just logging it for now.

I call it with, say:

```py
scrapy runspider myfolder\kwdSpider.py -a filename=myfolder\urls.txt -a delay=10 -a start_line=124
```

Because the url lists can be quite large I implemented the option to restart crawling from the specified start_line (and used `yield Request()`). It actually all works fine, EXCEPT this:

```py
E:\Python27>scrapy runspider mysite\kwdSpider.py -a filename=example\urls.txt -a delay=8 -a start_line=124
E:\Python27\example\kwdSpider.py:5: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: kwdSpider.MySpider inherits from deprecated class scrapy.spider.BaseSpider, please inherit from scrapy.spider.Spider. (warning only on first subclass, there may be others)
  class MySpider(BaseSpider):
2017-12-06 12:27:35+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.25.1 started (bot: scrapybot)
2017-12-06 12:27:35+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2017-12-06 12:27:35+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {}
2017-12-06 12:27:35+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2017-12-06 12:27:35+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2017-12-06 12:27:35+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2017-12-06 12:27:35+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
2017-12-06 12:27:35+0100 [example] INFO: Spider opened
2017-12-06 12:27:35+0100 [example] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-12-06 12:27:35+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2017-12-06 12:27:35+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 127.0.0.1:6081
124
125
126
127
128
129
130
131
132
133
134
135
136
137
138
139
2017-12-06 12:27:38+0100 [example] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/139th url> (referer: None)
140
2017-12-06 12:27:47+0100 [example] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/140th url> (referer: None)
141
```

See the way that the first dozen or so URLs are skipped? I'm obviously not understanding properly how the spider works, is it not initialised before the start_requests routine has finished counting through the txt file (which is by the way the only way I could think to implement this)?

Bonus question - what's this notice about?

```py
@kwdSpider.MySpider inherits from deprecated class scrapy.spider.BaseSpider, please inherit from scrapy.spider.Spider. (warning only on first subclass, there may be others)
  class MySpider(BaseSpider):
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does it eventually go back to the URLs it skipped. I believe that it doesn't work linearly, limiting the rate it will hit any one domain. Could that be your issue?

Comment: I don't believe so, no, at least it's not written to the log, nor does the console output indicate that it does. Both the log and the console just continue -
 lines 140, 141, 142, 143, etc. and never get back to the ones that were skipped. I would say the spider is not getting those first dozen lines.

Comment: Does it make a difference if your start line is a different number, say 140? Just trying to rule out that there is not a problem with the URLs it is skipping, or an issue with file format. Maybe also add `url.strip()` to your print statement to show what should be going through reflects reality

Comment: Oh no, it makes no difference what the start_line number is, or what the sample data is. It does the same thing no matter what file I feed it or what line I start at, I have already thrown quite a few different files at it, it does the same thing... Which print statement did you mean? The only one there prints the current line number which is an int...

Comment: yes, the print before the yield. I'd also print the url there, and possibly the current time (or log the same way as you are in the parse function). I'd like to see that those skipped items aren't happening during the initial delay of 5 seconds you have set.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean, for debugging purposes. Well, you just partly solved the mystery, I think. I won't post the output now, but it does print the correct URL, AND, when I output the crawled content (shove it out to the console from the parser) it has indeed fetched it. There is a strange delay before it prints out those initial dozen lines, but in fact it was fetching them. However that is bad because I don't think it's respecting the `download_delay`. Maybe I could resolve that by adding a 'time.sleep(self.delay)' before each `yield Request ()`, seems a bit of a kludge though...

Comment: The delay is on subsequent requests to the same domain, so if those first 12 are different domain names you won't see a delay. I believe that there is a setting to also delay based on IP address (so domains on the same server won't get hit hard).

Comment: Hmm, they are all the same domain - I am scraping my own site (long story!)

Comment: Have you tried just listing the first 12 URLs in the test list, to see if they are eventually crawled? Based on https://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/0.14/faq.html#does-scrapy-crawl-in-breath-first-or-depth-first-order I think that URLs are not crawled linearly, so that may explain why your first items are pushed into a queue until later.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer the bonus question, while investigations are ongoing with the primary issue.

Regarding the warning:

```
@kwdSpider.MySpider inherits from deprecated class scrapy.spider.BaseSpider, please inherit from scrapy.spider.Spider. (warning only on first subclass, there may be others)
 class MySpider(BaseSpider):
```

Following the message to the word, change the code to:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.http.request import Request
import time

class MySpider(Spider):
```

That should resolve that issue at least.